# Alterar a ordem do facet_wrap no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Veja o código abaixo, que gera o gráfico que vem logo a seguir:

```
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(sleepstudy, aes(x=Days, y=Reaction)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, color="black") +
  facet_wrap(~ Subject, nrow=3)
```

[image: Exemplo]

Ele mostra o tempo de reação (Reaction) de cada sujeito (308, 309, ..., 372) após alguns dias com privação de sono (Days). Note que cada um dos painéis tem uma reta ajustada aos dados, com inclinações diferentes.

Eu gostaria de obter um gráfico similar a este, exceto pela ordem dos sujeitos. Eu gostaria que eles estivessem ordenados não pela ordem crescente dos seus números, mas sim pela ordem crescente da inclinação das retas ajustadas dentro de cada painel.

Por exemplo, eu gostaria que o primeiro sujeito fosse o 335. O segundo, o 309, e assim por diante.

Como posso usar o ggplot2 para fazer isto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue um código para isso. O `ggplot` ordena os gráficos de acordo com a ordem dos fatores da variável `Subject`, se ela não for um fator ele converte em fator primeiro.

Portanto, o que fiz aqui, foi recriar a variável `Subject` com os fatores ordenados pela inclinação da reta de regressão.

```
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)


obter_beta <- function(y, x){
  coef(lm(y ~ x))[2]
}

sleepstudy %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  mutate(Beta = obter_beta(Reaction, Days)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Subject = fct_reorder(Subject, Beta)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Days, y=Reaction)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, color="black") + 
  facet_wrap(~ Subject, nrow=3)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]